# Why does only the first filter for "show more" work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2

On the webshop for my internship I'm trying to resolve a filter problem.
On each page, only the first filter works when you press "show more". On all other filters nothing happens once you press "show more".

This is the code responsible:

```js
function _toConsumableArray(e) {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        for (var o = 0, s = Array(e.length); o < e.length; o++) s[o] = e[o];
        return s;
    }
    return Array.from(e);
}
function showLessMore(e) {
    var o = e.target;
    if (qty.hasClass("js-hook__amshopby-more")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = o.parentNode.parentNode,
            a = s.querySelectorAll(".js-hook__amshopby-item");
        if (a.length) {
            for (var r = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(a)), t = 0; t < r.length; t++) {
                var l = r[t];
                "none" == l.style.display && (l.classList.add("filter--visible"), (l.style.display = "block"));
            }
            (o.style.display = "none !important"), (s.querySelector(".js-hook__amshopby-less").style.display = "block !important");
        }
    }
    if (qty.hasClass(o, "js-hook__amshopby-less")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var n = o.parentNode.parentNode,
            y = n.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".js-hook__amshopby-item.filter--visible");
        if (y.length) {
            for (var i = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(y)), p = 0; p < i.length; p++) {
                var c = i[p];
                c.classList.remove("filter--visible"), (c.style.display = "none");
            }
            (o.style.display = "none !important"), (n.querySelector(".js-hook__amshopby-more").style.display = "block !important");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might help, if you'd use meaningful names of the variables ..?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`? The only jQuery thing in your script is `.hasClass()` (why do you use that at all when everything else is non-jQuery?) And why is `qty` a jQuery object?

Comment: @Andreas Magento has jQuery by default, so doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Did you use devtools to debug the code? What behavior did you observe there?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers so far. Well I used devtools and the main thing I noticed: only on the first filter the javascript event happens. On the other "show more" there's no such event applied, even though they're all made in the exact way.

Comment: @CherryDT I answered above. I was mainly wondering if there's something happening in these 2 functions that makes it only select the first "show more" and not all that are on the page.